# Launch a program every 12 hours

Tags: c#

I want to launch a method in a program every 12 hours.

What do I have to do ?

Do I have to use a Timer to doing this ?

I have this code :

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); //One second, (use less to add precision, use more to consume less processor time
int lastHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Start();
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(lastHour < DateTime.Now.Hour || (lastHour == 23 && DateTime.Now.Hour == 0))
     {
           lastHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
           YourImportantMethod(); // Call The method with your important staff..
     }

}
```

Can I adapt it to launch my program every 12 hours ?

Comment: What about the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Amen for the task scheduler. Make a console app that does this, and launch it every 12h from the scheduler

Comment: How precise does "every 12h" have to be?

Comment: I can t use a task scheduler. I Want to Manage this timer in my code

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with async/await:

```
    private static async void RepeatedAction()
    {
        TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            YourImportantMethod();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Threading.Timer`

```
var start = TimeSpan.Zero;
var period = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    YourImportantMethod();   
}, null, start, period);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cron Jobs for this situation

Here is [url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10992/Implementing-a-small-Cron-service-in-C) check and implement. In corn job you can set when your program run

Comment: yea cron job , typo mistake